# homebrew error The following directories are not writable by your user:

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew

When I tried to install Python 3 through Homebrew,
I got the following message. How can I fix this error?

I’m not familiar with command line, so I would appreciate
if you could provide me with the exact commands to execute
to resolve the issue.

```
Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/share/man/man7

You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/man/man7

And make sure that your user has write permission.
  chmod u+w /usr/local/share/man/man7
```

Answer (score 21):

You have to change ownership on the mentioned directory by running the command:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/man/man7
```

Comment: sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/man/man8

Answer (score 6):

None of the other answers worked for me.

I solved it by running

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share
```

Instead of the specific path it was asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error all of sudden while it was working fine till yesterday. well resolved it by changing the ownership with below command:-

```
sudo chown -R $<whoami>:<id -g> /usr/local/share/man/man7
```

`id -g` is to get the group name and `whoami` to get the username.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this exact error recently when I tried to install mySQL : `The following directories are not writable by your user:`

I followed the below steps that fixed it :-

Run the below command lines in your terminal

```
brew doctor
```

This will take a while to run, once completed it will highlight some warnings that will help with debugging if any issues. For me, It prompted the below.

> Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew cleanup`

The issue was fixed finally after running `brew cleanup`, and I was able to then download MySQL with the below command with no issues.

```
brew install mysql
```